# Why is JsFiddle giving not defined error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

Take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fXfSz/:

If you look in the console it `shiftLeft` is undefined but it is defined like so:

```
function shiftLeft()
{
    for (var char in $('#chars').children())
    {
        log(char);
        char.css({left:char.position().left -100});
    }
}
```

Comment: You've wrapped it in a closure.

Comment: Your attempt is wrong on so many levels that I'm afraid correcting the mistake that leads to the error you see won't really help you.

Comment: For kicks, here is how your code *should* look like: http://jsfiddle.net/fXfSz/2/.

Comment: @Tomalak before I could debug the function I had to get it calling correctly!

Comment: @david_adler No offense, but you are still struggling with the basics of JavaScript and the DOM (I'm not even talking about jQuery yet). Banging on something until it kind of works is not the best way to learn, IMHO. There are millions of tutorials, I really think you should read a few of them first.

Comment: For those interested this was what I was trying to achieve http://jsfiddle.net/fXfSz/11/

Comment: @david If "you are missing some serious basics" is offensive to you, I can't help it. I can't think of a less "offensive" way to put that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `shiftLeft` function isn't defined in the global scope but in the one of the `onload` event handler.

Remove it from the `onload` function code and change the fiddle wrapping setting to "no wrap - in head". Or, better, bind it using the `click` function.

But you have other bugs in your function. Maybe you want this :

```
<button id="idofthebutton">Left</button>
<script>
$('#idofthebutton').click(function(){
    $('#chars').children().each(function(){
         $(this).css({left:$(this).position().left -100});
    });
});
</script>
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/khpyk/)

Answer (score 4):

Because the function `shiftLeft` is not defined in the global scope. It is local to the function that you assign to `onload` (a function that never runs because you have configured JSFiddle to only run the function that does that assignment `onload` too).

Bind your event handlers with JavaScript, not with `onclick` attributes.

```
function shiftLeft()
{
    for (var char in $('#chars').children())
    {
        // log is not a global
        console.log(char);
        char.css({left:char.position().left -100});
    }
}

function assignHandlers() {
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', shiftLeft);
}


// If you weren't using JSBin to run this onload:
// addEventListener('load', assignHandlers);
// but since you are:
assignHandlers();
```

Comment: `querySelector()`? `addEventListener()`? Why? The OP is using jQuery.