# jQuery Add row to table with dynamic ids'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/waH5S/6/

```
function add_row_retail() {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var table = document.getElementById("Retail");
                var row = table.insertRow(-1);
                var row_id = $('#Retail').val('tr[id]:last');
                console.log(row_id);
                var cell_init = row.insertCell(-1);
                cell_init.innerHTML = "blank";
            });
        }
```

I am trying to get the id of the table row(`<tr>`) before the added row, and then add 1 to this, with proper parseint(...).  Then doing the same with the cell (`<td>`) next, so that every cell has a unique id for each table.  I can't seem to find the row's id.

HERE IS THE "CORRECT" CODE FOR MY QUESTION

```
function add_row_retail() {
    var table = document.getElementById("Retail");

    // Row id
    var row_id = $('#Retail tr:last').attr('id');
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var next_row_id = "tr_" + (1+parseInt(row_id.match(/\d+/)[0],10));
    $(row).attr('id', next_row_id);

    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        var cell_id = $('#Retail td:last').attr('id');
        console.log(cell_id);
        var next_cell_id = "td_" + (1+parseInt(cell_id.match(/\d+/)[0],10));        console.log(next_cell_id);
        var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        $(cell).attr('id', next_cell_id);
        $(cell).innerHTML = "blank";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work for a number of reasons.  You've included the code "onload" so it is not accessible to the inline click handler.  Then when that is fixed, there doesnt' appear to be an element with `id` Retail in your html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `$('#Retail').val('tr[id]:last');` I think you want:

```
var row_id = $('#Retail tr:last').attr('id')
```

This selector finds the last tr under the `#Retail` element, and returns its `id` attribute.

jQuery last selector: http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

---

Next problem: IDs cannot start with numbers. Rename your IDs like "tr_1", "tr_2", etc.

---

Next problem: To extract the numbers from a string:

```
"tr_123".match(/\d+/)[0]; // returns 123.
```

Add 1 to it:

```
var next_id = "tr_" + (1+parseInt("tr_123".match(/\d+/)[0],10));
```

---

Then, set your new id.

```
var row = table.insertRow(-1);
...
$(row).attr('id', next_id);
```

Comment: `id` values can start with numbers in html5.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/waH5S/28/ that is the latest code, and now I am getting a function not defined. I wasn't getting this before.  Searches of StackOverflor yielded this http://jsfiddle.net/fXfSz/2/.  I tried to change the function itself to look like [link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770009/why-is-jsfiddle-giving-not-defined-error) that users fiddle, but then it gave me .match property of both row_id and cell_id were undefined.  I hope this explains it all.

Comment: It's a configuration issue. Change the include to "in body" like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/n6fjaa56tp9jipg/Screenshot%202014-04-25%2012.11.25.png -- Also, remove the `$(` and `)` from the second function.

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waH5S/31/) still getting undefined, even with the changes you've said to make.  Added a console.log to see row_id, which for some reason is undefined.(No clue why, the HTML has an id)

Comment: Nevermind!  I found my error!  I told it to insert the row, before getting the last    <tr> element so the jQuery selector couldn't find an    id in the last    <tr>.